# Drag and Drop запрет наложения элемента один на другой

Tags: drag-n-drop, javascript, html, css, вёрстка

[image]

Как сделать так, чтобы нельзя было накладывать один элемент на другой?

Я создаю два квадрата, затем начинаю их перетаскивать, и когда я один перетаскиваемый квадрат в процессе подношу ко второму квадрату и отпускаю, должно произойти так, чтобы элемент не смог наложиться поверх другого, а, к примеру, вернулся в свое исходное положение или разместился рядом с тем элементом, на который не смог "лечь".

Comment: @Саша Осадчий, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо хранить все перетаскиваемые объекты в массиве. На событии отпускания (mouseup) проверяете, пересекается ли ваш перетаскиваемый квадрат с другими. Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
var rectangles = [ document.querySelector("#rect1") /*, ...*/];
var activeRect, activeRectCoords; // перетаскиваемый прямоугольник
var isIntersects = function(it){
    var coords = it.getBoundingClientRect();

    // находится ли перетаскиваемый прямоугольник
    // между верхней и нижней границей перескиваемого
    if (activeRectCoords.top > coords.top &&
       activeRectCoords.top < coords.top + coords.height) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
if (rectangles.some(isIntersects)) {
    // возвращаете старые координаты, например
}
```